# td a hover getting really stuck in here

Tags: html, css, html-table

im new in web apps please be nice
i tried creating navigation using table and a tags
and it build this way

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
td a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="navigation" border="solid 2">
  <tr>
    <td class="1"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Registrasi</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Panduan</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Hubungi Kami</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

what i really want it is each td growing longer
which mean i want to put some space at the top and bottom of the link to make em look gorgeous

but when i hovering it, but it totally doesn't make any sense.
all of em growing longer at the same time, even if i hovering the first td
the last td do the same.

please help.. :(
sorry for my english

Comment: I'm not sure a table can do what you want, you may need to use `div`s styled to look like table `td`s.

Comment: i'm just trying using table :/ but by the way thx @Trug

Comment: hey why do i get that minus?? -_-"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your table row is increasing with the :hover because all your row cells are sharing the same height.

Try to use `ul` and `li` elements for your menu. It's better semantically and it will solve your problem.

Comment: i'm trying using div now...
but i will trying using ul li after this :D
thx man

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle/plunkr and explain what you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that only with TD. Basically, the adjacent cells have the same height in a table row.
The only way to make cells having different heights is using rowspan, but the result won't look as you want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you look for something like transform:scale(); ? it would increase size at screen but not the element itself within the flux.

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  transition: 0.25s
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
td:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<table class="navigation" border="solid 2">
  <tr>
    <td class="1"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Registrasi</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Panduan</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Hubungi Kami</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

or negative margin, but useless cause you won't see much (background added  for the demo and understanding)

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background:gray;
}
td a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 0;
  margin:-25px 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="navigation" border="solid 2">
  <tr>
    <td class="1"><a href="#">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Registrasi</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Panduan</a>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#">Hubungi Kami</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the best answer is using ul and li
it's easier and it's faster

```css
a{
 text-decoration:none;
}

li{
 list-style:none;
 display:inline-block;
 border:2px solid;
 padding:2%
}
.nav1 a:hover{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:100% 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="nav1"><a href="#">1</a></li
><li class="nav1"><a href="#">2</a></li
><li class="nav1"><a href="#">3</a></li
><li class="nav1"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

thx guys :)

Comment: reset your vertical-align and maybe line height to ul and then lis , it is a bit jumpy :)